# Using target risk or target return in R package fPortfolio

Tags: r, finance, portfolio

I use the R package fPortfolio for portfolio optimization for a rolling portfolio (adaptive asset allocation). Therefore, I use the backtesting function.

I aim at constructing a portfolio for a set of assets for a predefined target return (and minimized risk) or for a predefined target risk and maximized returns.

Even allowing for short selling (as proposed in another post 5 years ago) seems not to work. Besides, I do not want to allow for short selling in my approach.

I cannot figure out why changing values for target return or target risk do not influence the solution at all.
Where do I go wrong?

```
require(quantmod)
require(fPortfolio)
require(PortfolioAnalytics)

tickers= c("SPY","TLT","GLD","VEIEX","QQQ","SHY")
getSymbols(tickers)

data.raw = as.timeSeries(na.omit(cbind(Ad(SPY),Ad(TLT),Ad(GLD),Ad(VEIEX),Ad(QQQ),Ad(SHY))))
data.arith = na.omit(Return.calculate(data.raw, method="simple"))

colnames(data.arith) = c("SPY","TLT","GLD","VEIEX","QQQ","SHY")

cvarSpec <- portfolioSpec(
  model = list(
    type = "CVAR",
    optimize = "maxReturn",
    estimator = "covEstimator",
    tailRisk = list(),
    params = list(alpha = 0.05, a = 1)),
  portfolio = list(
    weights = NULL,
    targetReturn = NULL,
    targetRisk = 0.08,
    riskFreeRate = 0,
    nFrontierPoints = 50,
    status = 0),
  optim = list(
    solver = "solveRglpk.CVAR",
    objective = NULL,
    params = list(),
    control = list(),
    trace = FALSE))

backtest = portfolioBacktest()
setWindowsHorizon(backtest) = "12m"

assets <- SPY ~ SPY + TLT + GLD + VEIEX + QQQ + SHY

portConstraints ="LongOnly"

myPortfolio = portfolioBacktesting(
  formula = assets,
  data = data.arith, 
  spec = cvarSpec,
  constraints = portConstraints,
  backtest = backtest,
  trace = TRUE)  

setSmootherLambda(myPortfolio$backtest) <- "1m"
myPortfolioSmooth <- portfolioSmoothing(myPortfolio)
backtestPlot(myPortfolioSmooth, cex = 0.6, font = 1, family = "mono")
```